# In a synthetic control method, does the measured time have to be continuous?

Tags: r

I have been posting some questions regarding the synthetic control method the past few days as I keep encountering problems. My current problem, amongst others, is that I seem to get error messages regarding the timespan over which I have conducted my research. I am measuring data related to election dates, as such, my data is not measured on a continuous time period, but it has gaps in it. Now if I run my code I get the following error:

"time period 1949 from time.predictors.prior not found in time.variable"

It is true, I have no measure in 1949, but I do have measurements in 1948 and 1952. My question is, how do I solve this problem?

I have tried creating a continuous timescale, but doing this will give me data that is incorrect, as the nature of the data does not allow me to measure the data on a continuous scale.

`dataprep_outcomes <- dataprep(foo=dataset [dataset$Year %in% c(1948:1986),],
+                               predictors = c("Income","Distance","Gini","Percentage_voted","Protest"),
+                               dependent = c("Percentage_voted"),
+                               unit.variable = c("Municipality_No"),
+                               time.variable = c("Year"),
+                               treatment.identifier = 1, 
+                               controls.identifier = c(2:14),
+                               time.predictors.prior = c(1948:1967),
+                               time.optimize.ssr = c(1948:1986),
+                               unit.names.variable = c("Municipality_ID"),
+                               time.plot = c("Year"))}`

I would like to solve this problem, it would be very helpful, and I would be very grateful as a layman to hear from suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without access to your data, I can't confirm that this will work. However, it looks like the problem is that you're telling the function that the prior time periods are 1948 to 1967, when in fact they're only a subset of those dates. A solution might be to specify `time.predictors.prior = intersect(1948:1967, dataset$Year)`, which will ensure that the only values you use for time.predictors.prior are ones which are in your data.

You need to be sure that any time range you specify only includes observed dates, which means you'll need to tweak the date ranges in `time.optimize.ssr` as well. Here's an example using the built-in `basque` dataframe (in the Synth package). Just note that everywhere a range of years is specified, we need to ensure that it only contains observed years. I'm doing that with intersect, but there are other approaches. In your function this will be much easier, since you only specify a range of years in two places, as far as I can see.

```
data(basque)

basque <- subset(basque, !year %in% c(1965, 1966)) # remove two of the "prior" years

# dataprep: prepare data for synth
dataprep.out <-
  dataprep(
    foo = basque
    ,predictors= c("school.illit",
                   "school.prim",
                   "school.med",
                   "school.high",
                   "school.post.high"
                   ,"invest"
    )
    ,predictors.op = c("mean")
    ,dependent     = c("gdpcap")
    ,unit.variable = c("regionno")
    ,time.variable = c("year")
    ,special.predictors = list(
      list("gdpcap",intersect(1960:1969, basque$year),c("mean")),                            
      list("sec.agriculture",intersect(basque$year, seq(1961,1969,2)),c("mean")),
      list("sec.energy",intersect(basque$year, seq(1961,1969,2)),c("mean")),
      list("sec.industry",intersect(basque$year, seq(1961,1969,2)),c("mean")),
      list("sec.construction",intersect(basque$year, seq(1961,1969,2)),c("mean")),
      list("sec.services.venta",intersect(basque$year, seq(1961,1969,2)),c("mean")),
      list("sec.services.nonventa",intersect(basque$year, seq(1961,1969,2)),c("mean")),
      list("popdens",1969,c("mean")))
    ,treatment.identifier  = 17
    ,controls.identifier   = c(2:16,18)
    ,time.predictors.prior = intersect(1964:1969, basque$year)
    ,time.optimize.ssr     = intersect(1964:1969, basque$year)
    ,unit.names.variable   = c("regionname")
    ,time.plot            = intersect(c(1955:1997), basque$year)
  )
```

Comment: Dear Joseph, I have tried your string of code, but it still gave me the same error. Thank you nevertheless for your input! It might be useful information that I made my dataset in Windows Excel, perhaps the problem lies in the manner in which I saved the data, yet I cannot see how.

Comment: Can you post data so I can see what works and what doesn't? This seems like an interesting question, but it's hard for me to check.

Comment: Dear Joseph Clark McIntyre, I cannot thank you enough for this suggestion, it did indeed erase the error message! This has helped me incredibly. However, I have encountered another problem as layman and that is that I have gotten the following error "Error in as.vector(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default". However, if correctly, I filled in my 'y' as far as I am concerned?

Comment: Very glad to hear it.